# What does "pinned" icon of a class in Intellij IDEA mean?

Tags: intellij-idea, icons

[`org.apache.commons.validator.routines.CodeValidator`](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/validator/tags/VALIDATOR_1_5_1/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/CodeValidator.java?revision=1741724&view=markup) class of Apache Commons Validator library is presented as "pinned class" icon. What does it mean? I don't see any unusual things it this class.
[image: idea screenshot]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/symbols.html), the "pinned" symbol represents a final Java class.
As you can see with the link you provided, the CodeValidator class is, indeed, final.